# Textview no muestra texto en el emulador

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

tengo un scrollview con un linear layout, una imagen y un textview y al ejecutar la aplicación el texto no se ve y no entiendo por qué. ¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

Al ejecutar la aplicación el scroll funciona, la imagen se ve, al hacer scroll la imagen se mueve hacia arriba, pero el texto no se ve, he probado a cambiar los márgenes y tamaños de casi todo pero nada.

Y pocos detalles que puedo añadir más, tengo implementado el viewbinding y poco más, es un proyecto prácticamente nuevo.

PD: No hay nada implementado por código a parte del viewbinding

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/outlinedTextField"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/label"
        app:counterTextColor="@color/black"
        app:boxStrokeColor="@color/black"
        app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="20dp"
        app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="20dp"
        app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="20dp"
        app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="20dp"

        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

            />


    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        android:id="@+id/outlinedTextField2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/label"
        app:counterTextColor="@color/black"
        app:boxStrokeColor="@color/black"
        app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="20dp"
        app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="20dp"
        app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="20dp"
        app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="20dp"

        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/texto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

            />


    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>





    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="180dp">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
                android:src="@drawable/girl"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="35dp"
                android:text="@string/texto" />
        </LinearLayout>


        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>









    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/mi_barra"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_menu"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomAppBar.Colored"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_scrolling"
        app:hideOnScroll="true"/>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_buttom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_lapiz"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/mi_barra" />







</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En fin, después de pegarme horas buscando soluciones, la encuentro al poco de publicar la pregunta ‍♂️, El problema era que el linearlayout no tenía orientación.

El ide no me marca el error de la orientación, que tampoco sé porque:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El mismo android estudio te da un error de compilación porque a tu LinearLayout le hace falta orientacion. Pon más atención a esos errores que te da el IDE

Comment: Eso es lo más raro, no ha dado ningún error en ningún momento, he tenido que verlo yo. Creeme que no habría estado horas buscando si fuese así. Edito la respuesta para que lo veas.